# 403 Increasing the number of Parents is not allowed Google Drive API React Native

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, google-drive-api

I am using react-native-google-drive-api-wrapper.
It has been almost 4 months that my code was working completely fine. But now, suddenly I am not able to upload file on any folder in Google drive via React Native app.
I don't think that this is an issue of exceeding limits or something, because I am able to upload file on root folder, but not to any folder/subfolder.

Error is:

403 Increasing the number of Parents is not allowed Google Drive API React Native

Log:

```
>{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"cannotAddParent",
"message":"Increasing the number of parents is not allowed"}],
"code":403,"message":"Increasing the number of parents is not allowed"}}
```

Kindly help!

Comment: Did you try researching the error message?

Comment: Of course I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Have a look at the [updated behavior](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-single-parent):

> Beginning Sept. 30, 2020, you will no longer be able to place a file in multiple parent folders; every file must have exactly one parent folder location. Following is a summary of behavior changes related to the Drive API's new single-parent model.

There is a [guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/multi-parenting) on how to migrate your app to the single-parent model - I recommend you to follow it.

Comment: I see, let me check it. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Thanks for your tip, as I was using wrapper so this link has the solution.
https://github.com/RobinBobin/react-native-google-drive-api-wrapper/issues/35